# Unramified section associated to a rational point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, fundamental-group

This is a question for those familiar with the section conjecture, so I'll do away with the definition of a ramification map in this case. Here is the definition of a ramification map from an etale cohomological point of view:

For a number field $k$ and a smooth geometrically connected curve $X$ over $k$, let $X^0$ denote the set of closed points of $X$ and $k(X)$ denote the function field of $X$, we have an exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow \mathrm{Br}(X) \rightarrow \mathrm{Br}(k(X)) \rightarrow \bigoplus _{v \in X^0} H^1(G_v, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^3(X,\mathbb{G}_m),$$

where $G_v = \mathrm{Gal}(k(v)_s/k(v))$, with $k(v)$ a perfect field for all $v$. We say that a point $v \in X^0$ is *unramified* if the corresponding *ramification* (or *residue*) map

$$\mathrm{Br}(k(X)) \rightarrow H^1(G_v, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$$ is trivial. This is essentially taken from Milne's EC.

Now let $\mathrm{Gal}_k$ denote the absolute Galois group of $k$ and $H(k,X)$ be the set of sections $s: \mathrm{Gal}_k \rightarrow \pi_1(X)$ modulo $\pi_1(\bar{X})$-conjugacy. It is known that a section $s_v \in H(k,X)$ arising from a rational point $v \in X(k)$ is unramified, this is Lemma 84 of Stix's lecture notes *Rational points and the arithmetic of fundamental groups*.

For an unramified section $s_v$, does it follow that the ramification map
$\mathrm{Br}(k(X)) \rightarrow H^1(G_v,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$
of the associated rational point $v$ is trivial?

Please let me know if these concepts are completely unrelated, or if they are, some ways of thinking about a connection would be appreciated.